# How to save paraview data to file with all paraview properties

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

The result I have in Paraview:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TdeL.png)

I would like to save my project in Paraview to file (vtk or others).
For example, when I open the vtk file next time, it should be open with axes Grid and color properties.

Is there a way to export or write file to solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Try to provide an example of what you've already tried. Also make sure you've check out the [docs](https://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/index.html).

Comment: I have a vtk file (aray that consists points position). I opened this, changed properties (add axies Grid, change colors, Representation, size, etc.) Then when I save data as vtk or other extention and open again, it opens with default properties. (Sorry if have mistakes in English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to File > Save State...

Then, to reopen it, File > Load State...

It should do the work.

Comment: Sorry, I have already tried, but I want to save like data (vtk, csv or another)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I go to File > Save State (type of file: python state file)

Comment: Is there a way to open Paraview and load state from another python command line?
So, I want to write code that open paraview and load state.